# How to go through matrix by spiral from center in node.js?

Tags: node.js

I have a method in my project which goes through matrix and looking for needed colors:

```
for (let i = startXPoint; i <= endXPoint; i++) {
        for (let j = startYPoint; j <= endYPoint; j++) {
            let {r,g,b} = Jimp.intToRGBA(img.getPixelColor(i, j))
            let colorFound = checkColor(r,g,b);
            if (colorFound) {
                // do some stuff
            }
        }
}
```

The problem is that I need to find the closest to the center matched color instead of going through from left bottom corner to the top right one. Is there a way to do it via spiral search instead of search by lines as I did?